# MacOS build and run VSCode source

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

I'm newbie to NodeJS and trying to build and run visual studio code source on MacOS but got errors at step of install dependencies after run "yarn install" under vscode source path. Here is what I got:

```
>yarn install
yarn install v1.5.1
$ node build/npm/preinstall.js
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info windows-foreground-love@0.1.0: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "windows-foreground-love@0.1.0" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info windows-mutex@0.2.0: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "windows-mutex@0.2.0" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info windows-process-tree@0.2.1: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "windows-process-tree@0.2.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/14] ⡀ gc-signals:  ^
[6/14] ⡀ native-watchdog: ^
[3/14] ⡀ keytar: CXX(target) Release/obj.target/keytar/src/async.o
[4/14] ⡀ native-is-elevated: 6 errors generated.
error An unexpected error occurred: "/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/vscode/node_modules/native-is-elevated: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c node-gyp rebuild
Directory: /Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/vscode/node_modules/native-is-elevated
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@8.11.1 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [ '/Users/xxx/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/vscode/node_modules/native-is-elevated/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/xxx/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/xxx/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/<(target_arch)/iojs.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/vscode/node_modules/native-is-elevated',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/is-elevated/src/is-elevated.o
In file included from ../src/is-elevated.cc:1:
In file included from /Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/src/node.h:42:
/Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:15:2: error: unterminated conditional directive
#ifndef INCLUDE_V8_H_
 ^
/Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:8533:10: error: unknown type name 'c'
  static c
         ^
In file included from ../src/is-elevated.cc:1:
/Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/src/node.h:76:1: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
struct uv_loop_s;
^
In file included from ../src/is-elevated.cc:1:
In file included from /Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/src/node.h:42:
/Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:8494:7: error: missing '}' at end of definition of 'v8::internal::Internals'
class Internals {
      ^
/Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/src/node.h:80:1: note: still within definition of 'v8::internal::Internals' here
namespace node {
^
../src/is-elevated.cc:57:2: error: expected '}'
}
 ^
/Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:8409:20: note: to match this '{'
namespace internal {
                   ^
../src/is-elevated.cc:57:2: error: expected '}'
}
 ^
/Users/xxx/.node-gyp/iojs-1.7.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:64:14: note: to match this '{'
namespace v8 {
             ^
6 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/is-elevated/src/is-elevated.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/xxx/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
gyp ERR! command \"/opt/local/bin/node\" \"/Users/xxx/.yarn/bin/node-gyp\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/vscode/node_modules/native-is-elevated
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
```

Can anyone help? thx!

PS: I installed yarn in MacPorts, nodejs6 installed with it. I deactivated nodejs6 and installed nodejs8 with MacPorts. Before all these, I manually installed NodeJS with package downloaded.
Python active version is 2.7.10, with python3 installed.
MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Comment: First why are you building VSCode from source? Second, why are you using macports over homebrew? Third, this is an issue compiling the native binary `native-is-elevated`. Have you got XCode installed?

Comment: Xcode and command line tool is installed.

Answer (score 0):

workaround:

1. make a new folder, like myvscode
2. under myvscode, run yarn init
3. copy package.json from vscode to myvscode
4. under myvscode, run yarn
5. copy other files other than node_modules from vscode to myvscode

but still don't know how to fix the original issue.